# Convert double[,] to Variant*

Tags: c++, wpf, com, mfc, atl

In my application I'm trying to call a function of ATL COM class from my WPF application. ATL COM class's function's parameters are like this.

```
[id(5)] HRESULT GetFormationZPoints([in] BSTR sLyrName, [in,out] VARIANT* pLandingPoints);
```

And in WPF side, I am trying to pass a double's 2-D array like this

```
List<PointsVector> landingPoints = Planner.LandingPointsList;
double[,] dLPs = new double[landingPoints.Count, 3];
int i = 0;
foreach (PointsVector v in landingPoints)
{
    dLPs[i, 0] = v.X;
    dLPs[i, 1] = v.Y;
    dLPs[i, 2] = v.Z;
    i++;
}
gaInfo.GetFormationZPoints(targetReservoir.TargetLayerName, ref dLPs);
```

I get the following error message:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'ref double[*,*]' to 'ref object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the exception , can you convert the dLPs variable to object and see whether it works . Basically it should look something like ,

```
    gaInfo.GetFormationZPoints(targetReservoir.TargetLayerName, ref (object) dLPs);
```

Comment: I tried this, but this does not compile. Gives error message "ref or out parameter must be an assignable value". So i tried this
    

    object obj = (object)dLPs;
    gaInfo.GetFormationZPoints(targetReservoir.TargetLayerName, ref obj);

So this work great. Many thanks for the help mate :)